# Tooltip is hidden by containing HTML element

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a chart that's in a div that's set to `overflow-y: scroll`. The tooltips spill out of the chart to the right and part of them can't be seen.

Apparently, CSS doesn't allow `overflow-y: scroll` and `overflow-x: visible` at the same time, hence the obscuration of the tooltips. I also had the same problem with a calendar but it has a setting that changes the direction that it expands.

Is there a way that I can reposition or offset the tooltips such that they expand to the left?

Here's a pic...

[image]

I thought this hack would work but it results in the div containing the charts becoming horizontally scrollable.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39554003/221683

Comment: paste the code man :)

Comment: The code works fine. I need to move a tooltip.

Comment: what is your tooltip? is it visible under mouseover action or what, it is printed along with the chart? Without the code the screen is piece of... you know what :)

Comment: Try add a min-width to tooltip container

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip shoud be outside the oveflow box if you want to show wider area of it. You can calculate its position in js on mouseover or any other action - without the code I do not know what are you showing, how, and why it is not working as you describe. "the code works fine" - apparently not, if you asked your question...

```
<style>
.container { position:relative; }
.tooltip { position:absolute; }
</style>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='tooltip'>Hi mum, this is long as hell tooltip, not overflowed</div>
    <div class='chart'>
    ... chart data
    </div>
</div>
```